# Create SparkSQL UDF with non serializable objects

Tags: scala, apache-spark, serialization, hive, udf

I'm trying to write an UDF that I would like to use on Hive tables in an sqlContext. Is it in any way possible to include objects from other libraries that are not serializable? Here's a minimal example of what does not work:

```
def myUDF(s: String) = {
 import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder
 val coder= new BASE64Encoder
 val encoded= decoder.encode(s)
 encoded
}
```

I register the function in the spark shell as udf function

```
val encoding = sqlContext.udf.register("encoder", myUDF)
```

If I try to run it on a table "test"

```
sqlContext.sql("SELECT encoder(colname) from test").show()
```

I get the error

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
object not serializable (class: sun.misc.BASE64Encoder, value: sun.misc.BASE64Encoder@4a7f9a94)
```

Is there a workaround for this? I tried embedding myUDF in an object and in a class but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try defining `udf` function as

```
def encoder = udf((s: String) => {
  import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder
  val coder= new BASE64Encoder
  val encoded= coder.encode(s.getBytes("UTF-8"))
  encoded
})
```

And call the `udf` function as

```
dataframe.withColumn("encoded", encoder(col("id"))).show
```

**Updated**

As @santon has pointed out that `BASE64Encoder` encoder is initiated for each *row* in the *dataframe* which might lead to performance issues. The solution to that would be to create a *static object* of `BASE64Encoder` and call it within `udf` function.

Comment: thanks, your solution works as well, but later I realized that my problem was ill-posed and that I did get it working as well.

Comment: @Harpe, yes your way is correct too :) thanks for the upvote :) You can accept it if you want ;)

Comment: This code will also instantiate a new `BASE64Encoder` object for every single row, right? That might be okay in your application, but has potential performance implications. I'm struggling with a similar issue.

Comment: yes @santon you are absolutely correct about that. just create a static object of BASE64Encoder and access it from the udf function. I have updated the answer as well.

Comment: This link is also super useful. I used to to get around the serialization issue as well as the performance issue of instantiating an object for each row: https://www.placeiq.com/2017/11/how-to-solve-non-serializable-errors-when-instantiating-objects-in-spark-udfs/